# Add user id to comment model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, associations

I'm following this tutorial :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model

It works when using `commenter` and `comment` where the user can add a name and message but I want to associate the comment with a user id (I already have users)

It uses
`rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text post:references` but I want to replace `commenter:string` with a user id association (`user_id:integer`?). In a previous question someone suggested `author_id:integer` but it did not work. Not sure where to start and there doesn't seem to be any tutorials on the subject (I have read RoR help guides on associations etc but can't find the correct way to generate a user id with the comment model)

comments_controller.rb

```
def create
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
@comment = @listing.comments.create(params[:comment])
redirect_to listing_path(@listing)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the Comment mode like this:

> rails generate model Comment user:references body:text post:references

The `references` type you specify will actually create a `user_id:integer` column and adds a `belongs_to` association to the `Comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

If you do want to have a `Comment#commenter` association to refer to the user rather than `Comment#user`, you can define it in your `Comment` model as follows:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: How would i get the user id of a specific comment on the /posts/1 page where the comments and comment form are located? (so each comment had the user id next to it) When I look in the dev database the user_id for the comment is blank. How do I associate the user ID when creating a new comment (I will post my comments controller)

Comment: That would be with something like: `@post.comments.first.user_id`. Or you can just return the `User` instance: `@post.comments.first.user`.

Comment: To assign the user to a new comment, you need to get the current user instance and then use it to create the comment: `@comment = @listing.comments.create(params[:comment].merge(user: user))`. I'm assuming you're using Rails 3.2 or below btw.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.2

Comment: Then you need to use strong parameters or else the comment creation won't work properly. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller